# Find a line and replace the corresponding next line

Tags: shell, unix, notepad++

I am trying to find a userid and change the existing password with the new one.

Sample file:

```
$TestDBUser=TestUsr12
$TestDBPass=Rxa97Gtwbp/UcC
```

Now suppose the above combination exists at 100 times in a file I need to change the updated password for TestUsr12

Expected output:

```
$TestDBUser=TestUsr12
$TestDBPass=Ymw0tiwbplqxc
```

I have tried to do this with notepad ++ using \n in extended search mode but somehow its not working for all such listings.
Within a file there are multiple such combinations for different id's which needs to be replace with the new one for the respective id's.

Comment: why do you using shell, unix and notepad++ tags? notepad++ is for windows as I know.
You should read about regexp and use something like replace "TestDBUser=.*" with "TestDBUser=blablabla"

Comment: `sed -e 's@Rxa97Gtwbp/UcC@Ymw0tiwbplqxc@g'`

Comment: Hi William with the above sed command it will replace existing password with the new one everywhere, however as per the new password created it is different for all user id's, previously passwords were same for different user id's.

Comment: @Saboteur I tried following unix command sed '/$TestDBUser=TestUsr12/!b;n;c$TestDBPass=Ymw0tiwbplqxc'   As I am not sure of exact expression to be used in regex in notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

Using Notepad++, you can do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\$TestDBUser=TestUsr12\R\$TestDBPass=\KR.+$`
- Replace with: `Ymw0tiwbplqxc`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\$TestDBUser=TestUsr12      # literally
\R                          # any kind of linebreak
\$TestDBPass=               # literally
\K                          # forget all we have seen until this position
.+                          # 1 or more any character but newline
$                           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
Ymw0tiwbplqxc           # the new pswd
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]